# Does absolute convergence implies the uniform convergence on the compact subset?

Tags: complex-analysis

In the lecture notes that I'm reading, it always says something like "(the infinite sum defined on the complex) is absolutely and uniformly convergent hence holomorphic."

I know that we need to use the Weierstrass theorem, but the statement makes me wonder if absolute convergence on the complex plane implies uniform convergence on the compact set, which I knew as false. Should I attempt Weierstrass M-test in this case?

Comment: See [This Paper, Lemma 2.1](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2003.10263.pdf) for a couple of counterexamples.

Comment: Then could you give me any idea why they are usually in the same context? Does absolute convergence merely a way to show that it "at least" converges?